# Anúncio Interstitial com atraso no carregamento

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

Estou tentando implementar um anúncio interstitial, e gostaria que ele fosse carregado antes, no aplicativo está acontecendo dele carregar junto com a ação o que ocasiona delay e faz o anúncio aparecer bem depois. 
Quero fazer o anúncio aparecer logo após apertar "adicionar" como mostra na imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código abaixo mostra como foi implementado:

```js
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8920922366585510/4181958830");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        if (requestCode == ADD_PACK) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                if (data != null) {
                    final String validationError = data.getStringExtra("validation_error");
                    if (validationError != null) {
                        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                            //validation error should be shown to developer only, not users.
                            MessageDialogFragment.newInstance(R.string.title_validation_error, validationError).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "validation error");
                        }
                        Log.e(TAG, "Validation failed:" + validationError);
                    }
                } else {
                    new StickerPackNotAddedMessageFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "sticker_pack_not_added");
                }
            }
        }
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded()  {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Já tentei colocar a chamada de carregamento antes desses códigos mas não consigo fazer carregar antes.

```js
            mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8920922366585510/4181958830");
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

O aplicativo se trata de um código aberto do github, o link está logo abaixo caso queiram baixar pra ver o código completo e ajudar:
[DOWNLOAD CÓDIGO COMPLETO](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/tree/master/Android)